# How to create a consistent range of dates in excel?

Tags: excel

I have a combination of two reports into a master file. I'll be eventually transforming the data into a more readable format, but I have a date column that has two different types of date formats:

`(yyyy-mm-dd & mm/dd/yyyy)`

Is there a formula I can use to convert this so every cell reads: `mm/dd/yyyy`?

I know I can do it via text-to-columns, but that will take a bit longer than I'd like.

I will repost the question if it only can be done via VBA, but I figure there may be a way to just complete it via one formula and an auto fill.

Comment: If you want to change data within a cell, there is no way a formula could do that without helper cells. VBA can.

Comment: @Luuklag would this be a complex process in vba?

Comment: No not really. Just a simple loop, and some If's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably just use:

```
=DATEVALUE(A1)
```

And copy it down. You can then format the date to whatever format you like.

[DateValue()](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/datevalue-function-df8b07d4-7761-4a93-bc33-b7471bbff252) Takes a date stored as a string and converts to excel's date type.